# 'sep' parameter not working in sliderInput (Shiny 0.14)

Tags: r, slider, shiny, separator

after upgrading to Shiny 0.14, the `sep`parameter in sliderInput does not work for me anymore (although I am not 100 percent sure that upgrading is really the reason).

When I want to use a sliderInput widget for years, I obviously do not want to have any thousand separators. So I tried this in a minimal example:

```
shinyApp(
  ui = basicPage(
    sliderInput("test", label = "Test slider", min = 1953, max = 2014, step = 1, sep = "",
            value = 1990)
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
  }
)
```

And this is what I get on my system:

[image: Screenshot of broken 'sep' in Shiny 0.14]

Is Shiny 0.14 really the reason for this? Or am I doing something wrong? If I exchange `sep = ""`to `sep = ";"` (for example), it works the way it should (; is used as thousand separator).

Thanks for your help.

(I am running R 3.3.1 on Mac OS 10.11.6)

Comment: I honestly don't get what you're trying to do. Is there a proper question here?

Comment: @PorkChop: OP would like to remove the space in the numbers.

Comment: You may have to download the github version of Shiny for now.  See https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1369

Comment: Thanks for clearing up my question, Weihuang Wong. Looking forward to seeing that fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
        ui = basicPage(
                sliderInput("slider", "Time", min = as.Date("1953-01-01"),max =as.Date("2014-01-01"),value=as.Date("1990-01-01"),timeFormat="%Y")
        ),
        server = function(input, output) {
        }
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this solution. It works. I wanted to avoid declaring the years as dates because it involved changing a lot of other code in my application. But in the long run, it seems better to treat the years as dates.